# QtQuick 2 Transparent Window Background

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I've been searching how to make the **background** of my **QtQuick 2.0** application **transparent**.
Most answers I've found use QtDeclarative  which is ok for QtQuick 1.0 but not version 2.

Finally I found an answer that I will post but I would like to know if there is a better/simpler/smaller way to achieve this task.

**Note***

I wanna make the Background of the window transparent.
Some people suggest to setOpacity but this makes all the qml elements transparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution in this post http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/18984/#106629 by billouparis. He uses the main application template that is being generated by QtCreator which is pretty convenient. 
**Note:** I changed a little bit the original code to make it smaller.

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"
#include <QSurface>
#include <QSurfaceFormat>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;

    // Make Background Transparent Start
    viewer.setSurfaceType(QSurface::OpenGLSurface);

    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setAlphaBufferSize(8);
    format.setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::OpenGL);

    viewer.setFormat(format);
    viewer.setColor(QColor(Qt::transparent));
    viewer.setClearBeforeRendering(true);
    // Make Background Transparent Stop

    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/myProject/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Also make sure that the root qml element has an alpha color (Qt.rgba)

Comment: Hi George, I believe it will work even if you delete the lines that use QSurface and QSurfaceFormat. That will make your code even simpler.

Comment: Hi George, I have tried your code but am always getting a black background.Any Idea?

Comment: In your qml file is your root-element's color transparent ?

Answer (score 2):

here a example to get a frameless, transparent window in pure qml

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    id: backlight
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("backlight")
    width: 500
    height: 50
    x: (Screen.width - width) / 2
    y: (Screen.height - height) / 2
    color: "transparent"

    property real slideValue
    signal onSlide(real value)

    Rectangle {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: parent.width
        height: 50
        color: "transparent"

        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            radius: 25
            opacity: 0.3
            color: "gray"
        }

        Slider {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            width: backlight.width - 16
            height: backlight.height
            value: backlight.slideValue
            focus: true
            onValueChanged: backlight.onSlide(value)
            Keys.onSpacePressed: Qt.quit()
            Keys.onEscapePressed: Qt.quit()

            style: SliderStyle {
                groove: Rectangle {
                    implicitHeight: 8
                    radius: 4
                    color: "gray"
                }
                handle: Rectangle {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    color: control.pressed ? "white" : "lightgray"
                    border.color: "gray"
                    border.width: 2
                    width: 34
                    height: 34
                    radius: 17
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.0


 Window {
    id: backlight

    visible: true
    title: qsTr("backlight")
    width: 500
    height: 50
    x: (Screen.width - width) / 2
    y: (Screen.height - height) / 2
    color: "transparent"


    }
```

Comment: the simplicity of this answer makes it the best. worked on Qt 5.7, Quick 2.7, Win7