# Qt Quick2 window can't be transparent without aero

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm using Qt 5.7 on Windows 7.

I can make my QWindow have opacity, but it can't be transparent.

```
// window1.qml
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    color: "transparent"
} // no transparent, black background


// window2.qml
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    color: "transparent"
    opacity: 0.5
} // black but 50% opacity background
```

But if I enable aero, then it would be transparent without any problem.

I've read a lot of articles about it. but I couldn't find correct answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22554797/6356562 - set surface format

This answer doesn't work for me.

How can I solve it?

Comment: There is no solution yet. Without Aero, transparancy is not possible (yet). This had been [filed as a bug since Qt 5.6](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52494)

Comment: I faced similar issue with QT5.8. I could not get it to work. But I have seen some UI elements developed using openGL which are transparent on win7 without aero (Not QT). So technically it might be possible to do it with some work around.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code with `Qt 5.8`:

```
Window {
  width: 200
  height: 200
  visible: true

  color: "transparent"
  opacity: 0.9

  Button {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    text: "Click Me!"
  }
}
```

And I get this result:
[image: Transparent QtQuickControls2]
I recommend you use `Qt 5.8`.